# PDO: MVC How to Redirect User Login based on Usertype

Tags: php, authentication

I've been struggling and would like to know how to get my login form to redirect the user based on their user type. I have customer and admin as user types in the database. My code consists of a login page, login controller, data access page, user class page, and logout.

**Login Page**

```
<?php require_once ("../Controller/loginController.php"); ?>
<form action="" method= "POST">
    <br><br>
    Username:
    <input name="loginName"  placeholder="User Name">
    <br><br><br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="loginPassword"  placeholder="Password">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="button">    <span style="color: red"><?='<br><br>'. $error?></span>
</form>
```

**Login Controller Page**

```
<?php

require_once("../Model/dataAccess.php");
require_once("../Model/user.class.php");

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

if (!isset($error)) {
    $error = "";
}

if (isset($_SESSION["loggedInUser"])) {
    header('Location: ../View/account.php');
    die();
} else if (isset($_REQUEST["button"])) {
    $username    = !empty($_REQUEST["loginName"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["loginName"]) : null;
    $password    = !empty($_REQUEST["loginPassword"]) ? trim($_REQUEST["loginPassword"]) : null;
    $currentuser = getLogIn($username, $password);

    if ($currentuser) {
        $_SESSION["loggedInUser"] = $currentuser;
        $error                    = "You have logged in successfully";
        header('Location: ../View/account.php');
        die();
    }

    else {
        $error = "The login details supplied do not match any valid user.";
        header('Location: ../View/login.php');
    }
}
?>
```

**Logout Page**

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION["loggedInUser"]);
session_destroy();
$error = "You have successfully logged out.";
echo $error . '<br><br>';
echo 'Click <a href="login.php">here</a> to login.';
?>
```

**Data Access Page**

```
<?php

require_once('../Model/user.class.php');

function getLogIn($username, $password)
{
    global $pdo;
    $sqlUserLog  = 'SELECT userType FROM User WHERE userName= ? AND userPass= ?';
    $stmtUserLog = $pdo->prepare($sqlUserLog);

    if (!$stmtUserLog->execute(array(
        $username,
        $password
    ))) {
        die('Error');
    }
    $UserLog = $stmtUserLog->fetch();
    return $UserLog;
}
?>
```

**User Class Page**

```
 <?php

class User
{

    var $userID;
    var $userType;
    var $userName;
    var $userPass;

    function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }
    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `if(userLog=a){redirectToPage}else{redirectToAnotherPage}`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile can I do this in my login controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($currentuser)
{
    $_SESSION["loggedInUser"] = $currentuser;
    // its a bad programming practice to set as "error" a success message
    $error = "You have logged in successfully";

    if($currentuser['userType'] == 'admin'){
        header('Location: ../View/adminAccount.php');
    }
    else {
        header('Location: ../View/account.php');
    }
    die();
}
```

also have in mind it is a bad practice to store your passwords in plaintext, as I assume from this part `if(!$stmtUserLog->execute(array($username, $password))) {`

Comment: I have 2 files called account.php and adminAccount.php. This code isn't redirecting me.

Comment: I've updated the code and now it is logging me in to account.php every time.

Comment: Even if you login with another user? did u logout and destroy the sessions?

Comment: Yes I clicked on logout. And I logged back in with different details but account.php is consistent on both login details.

Comment: then the `$currentuser->userType` is not holding the variable you want to check or you are not even storing the user type as "admin". You have to check the proper variable at that point

Comment: My database has 2 rows: userID, userType, userName, userPass and the stored values are user01, Customer, Mike, mike01 and user02, Administrator, admin01, and admin01. I don't know what to do

Comment: Guys its working now. I had to change the line if($currentuser->userType == 'admin') to if($currentuser["userType"] == "Administrator")